# How do you query a model for an aggregate of a ForeignKey computed field

Tags: django, django-orm

How do you query a model for an aggregate of a ForeignKey 'computed' (Autofield?) field

I have two models:

```
class Job(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(…)

class LineItem(models.Model):
    job = models.ForeignKey(Job, …)
    metric_1 = models.DecimalField(…)
    metric_2 = models.DecimalField(…)
    metric_3 = models.DecimalField(…)
    # Making this a @property, @cached_property, or the like makes no difference
    def metric_total(self):
        return (self.metric_1 + self.metric_2 * self.metric_3)
```

In the view:

```
class StackoverflowView(ListView, …):
    model = Job

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Job.objects
            .select_related(…)
            .prefetch_related('lineitem_set')
            .filter(…).order_by(…)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context_data = super(StackoverflowView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context_data['qs_aggregate'] = self.get_queryset() \
            .annotate(
                # Do I need to Annotate the model?
            ).aggregate(
                # This works for any of the fields that have a model field type
                metric1Total=Sum('lineitem__metric_1'),
                metric2Total=Sum('lineitem__metric_2'),
                # This will error : 
                # Unsupported lookup 'metric_total' for AutoField or join on the field not permitted.
                # How do I aggregate the computed model field 'metric_total'?
                metricTotal=Sum('lineitem__metric_total'),
            )
        return context_data
```

When I try to aggregate the computed field, I get the error: `Unsupported lookup 'metric_total' for AutoField or join on the field not permitted.`.   How do I aggregate these special fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to ***calculate `metric_total`*** too

```
Job.objects.aggregate(
    metric1Total=Sum('lineitem__metric_1'),
    metric2Total=Sum('lineitem__metric_2'),
    metric_total=Sum('lineitem__metric_1') + Sum('lineitem__metric_2')
)
```

A possible dup: [Django @property used in .aggregate()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50341867/django-property-used-in-aggregate)

In short, these `annotate()` and `aggregate()` methods are performed on the Database level whereas the **`metric_total()` "method"** performs on the Python level.

Comment: anyway to 'link' the method(s) in the model files to the SQL query to /ensure/ that the math/comptation remains the same?

Comment: If we use *"proper math operators"*, the results will remain the same